# How do I set Australia/Melbourne timezone to a countdown timer using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How do I add Australia/Melbourne timezone to the code below so regardless of the users location it displays the correct time. I have `risul:moment-timezone` installed however everything I do just breaks the countdown. Any help is appreciated.

```
Template.countdownTimer.onRendered(function() { 
  var today = new Date(); 
  var sunday = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+(7-today.getDay()), 23, 59, 59);

  $('#countdown').countdown(sunday, function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%d days %H hours %M minutes %S seconds'));
  });

});
```

**Update**

```
var today = moment();
  var sunday = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+(7-today.getDay()), 23, 59, 59);

  console.log(sunday);
  var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(today, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true
  });
```

Comment: I can help you, but I need some clarification as to what you are trying to accomplish. None of your code here uses moment or moment timezone at all. Are you trying to count down to the end of the day on the nearest upcoming Sunday, Melbourne time?

Comment: I'm trying to count down to the upcoming sunday 11:59:59pm at this point the counter restarts

Comment: sorry Julien did you need something else

Comment: Your example doesn't show using moment or moment-timezone at all.  Show what you've tried that didn't work and we can help from there.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of things. Whenever I use moment.js it just breaks so it's hard to know what to show. If I change `today = moment();` I get the error getFullYear is not a function. Completely confused by momentjs.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it reading the momentjs documentation then as below:

```
let time = moment(date).parseZone("Australia/Melbourne");
return time.format('YYYY:MM:DD HH:mm:ss:SSS');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do for any country/Area for doing this you just have to know timezone

```
var timeZone = {hr:5, min:30} // for india
var utcOffset = parseInt(timeZone.hr) * 60 + parseInt(timeZone.min);
todayDate = moment().utcOffset(utcOffset);
```

Please user .format methods for trturning the value.
This will return the current time of any timezone.

Comment: No.  Don't do this.  Many time zones are not just fixed offsets. The `Australia/Melbourne` zone mentioned in the question rotates between `+10:00` and `+11:00` for daylight saving time.  Also, you should never adjust for time zones by adding or subtracting minutes.  That actually chooses a different point in time.  If you wanted to switch to a fixed offset, you can pass that in to the `utcOffset` function.

Comment: I found that when you pass some value in utcoffset(330), I think it should give you the current time in India. But It will don't do that. So what it basically does  add the minutes in the current time. But I think that is not what we want from moment. Here is sample pic that you can check here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QSvA_4-YCHT3A5UjRESzByTDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So Solving this issue what I did I subtract the current utcoffset time that we set the current time to utc time. then I add add some other country utc offset timezone, That will set the time to particular country timezone. So I mixed both things in single line. You can check it working and link is here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QSvA_4-YCHRmpTT2NLVXpXams/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You're not using moment correctly.  Please read [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/), including [the user guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/).  In particular, do not use the internal fields that start with `_`, such as `_d`.  You should instead be using the public API like `.format()`.

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson for making my concept more clear.